# Android automation test - Linux bash if condition fails while assigning command output to variable

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell

I am building testing environment to test android phones. As part of this environment I am searching for the existence of certain file in the Android (using "adb shell"). in case the file is found i would like to perform additional functionality in the PC connected to the Android.

Setup: Linux machine (ubuntu 12.04) connected to android phone.

The following bash script should perform this functionality:

```
#!/bin/bash
filelocation=`adb shell su -c "if [ -e '/proc/kmsg' ]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi"`

echo "file location: $filelocation"
if [ "$filelocation" == "0" ]
then
{
        echo "/proc/emmc was found"
}
else
        echo "/proc/emmc was NOT found"
fi
```

the output of this script is as follows:

> file location: 0
>
> /proc/emmc was NOT found

As you can see from its output the file was found ("file location" shows 0) but the bash if condition fails and i do not understand why.

To further understand the issue I have tried to replace the if condition for all supported bash brackets types (i.e. ((...)), [..] and [[...]] ) and all efforts failed. also , I have changed the condition itself from sting (==) comparison to integer comparison ( -eq ) and it also failed.

To verify my operation again i have created the following script, just to debug it:

```
#!/bin/bash

filelocation=`if [ -e /proc/kallsyms ]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi`

echo "file location: $filelocation"

if [ "$filelocation" == "0" ]
then
{
        echo "/proc/kallsyms was found"
}
else
        echo "/proc/kallsyms was NOT found"
fi
```

the output of this script is as follows:

> file location: 0
>
> /proc/kallsyms was found

Here the file is found.

**To conclude:**

In both cases, with ADB or locally on the Linux machine, "file location" shows proper location- i.e. "file location: 0"

However when using the if statement in the 1st script it fails(following the adb shell ).

I have searched the net and could not find solution to that case. any feedback would be great !

Comment: What does `echo "$filelocation" | od -a` output ? I suspect the presence of a special character (I think you get "0\n", the line break coming from your `echo` commands). Does it work better with `echo -n 0` and `echo -n 1` ?

Comment: @syme it was indeed hidden character... piping the adb output through `tr -d "\r\n"` solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I’ve taken my phone and test it. The point is that: by some weird reason `adb` returns strings with DOS line-ending (`\r\n`).

```
$ ISFILEEXISTS="$(adb shell '[ -e /proc/kmsg ]; echo $?')"
$ set | grep ISFILEEXISTS
ISFILEEXISTS=$'0\r'
```

So the proper statement may look like:

```
$ if [[ $ISFILEEXISTS == $'0\r' ]]; then echo Y; else echo N; fi
Y
```

But if what `adb` returns may be used again below, it would be much better to strip all extraneous chars at once:

```
ISFILEEXISTS="$(adb shell '[ -e /proc/kmsg ]; echo $?')"
ISFILEEXISTS="${ISFILEEXISTS%$'\r'}"
```

By the way, as you can see, `/proc/` filesystem is perfectly available for reading for non-privileged user so you do not need in `su`.

Comment: @Dmitry, Thanks for the quick response. indeed the "\r\n" was the troublemaker. passing the assignment of adb output through "tr -d" to delete the "\r\n" solved the issue.
the modified line is as follows : `filelocation=\`adb shell su -c "if [ -e '/proc/kmsg' ]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi" | tr -d "\r\n"\``

Comment: @Dimitry Checked the answer and tried to upvote. Unfortunately as I am indeed new to StackOverflow user my repetition is too low so i cannot upvote this time :-)